# Record navigation on a form

Tags: ms-access, vba

So I have been tasked with creating a tracking database & I am having an issue which is driving me crazy.

I have created an input form and for ease of use I need to create custom navigation buttons, again I have completed this and they work fine.
I have added code to the current event to disable the buttons if at the first record / last record - again this works fine.

This is where I have gotten stuck, as soon as I disable the built in navigation buttons it disables the custom buttons I have created. If I remove the current event code, again they work but not how I intend.

I would appreciate any help you could provide as I am still new to learning Access & I am sure this is a simple fix & something I am not doing correct - but I just cannot figure it out, I have included my code below.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdBack_Click()

    On Error Resume Next

    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acPrevious
End Sub

Private Sub cmdNew_Click()

    On Error Resume Next

    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
End Sub

Private Sub cmdNext_Click()

    On Error Resume Next

    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()

    On Error Resume Next

    If Me.CurrentRecord = 1 Then

        Me.cmdBack.Enabled = False

    Else
        Me.cmdBack.Enabled = True

    End If

    If Me.CurrentRecord >= Me.Recordset.RecordCount Then

        Me.cmdNext.Enabled = False

    Else
        Me.cmdNext.Enabled = True

    End If

    If Me.NewRecord Then

        Me.cmdNew.Enabled = False

    Else
        Me.cmdNew.Enabled = True

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your `DoCmd.` calls with navigation using the form recordset.

```vb
Me.Recordset.MoveNext 'alternative to DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext
Me.RecordSet.MovePrevious 'alternative to DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acPrevious
Me.RecordSet.AddNew 'alternative to DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for the updated code - I had to add the following line to get them to work as I intented though.

Me.RecordsetClone.MoveLast